App crashes on open and kotling problem during building apk flutter
I recently built my first flutter app and it went smooth but when i add google mobile ads interstitial ad or any kind really, it gives me this messaagr while building it :
"Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.6.0 #"
The app built after this message but upon installing the app on my android phone the app crashes and doesn't open, seems the problem is in google mobiles ads dependency, cuz by removing it and building it again it works fine.
I tried changing kotlin version in build.gradle file in android folder, yet the line missing , even tho other apps workd perfectly fine without it,
Ad placement :
class AdDisplay{
  final adUnitIdInterstitial = Platform.isAndroid
      ? 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712'
      : 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910';

   loadIntersitial (){
     InterstitialAd.load(
         adUnitId: adUnitIdInterstitial,
         request: const AdRequest(),
         adLoadCallback: InterstitialAdLoadCallback(
           // Called when an ad is successfully received.
           onAdLoaded: (ad) {
             debugPrint('$ad loaded.');
             // Keep a reference to the ad so you can show it later.
             showInterstitial(ad);
           },
           // Called when an ad request failed.
           onAdFailedToLoad: (LoadAdError error) {
             debugPrint('InterstitialAd failed to load: $error');
           },
         ));
  }

  void showInterstitial(InterstitialAd ad) {
     ad.show();
  }
}

ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      AdDisplay().loadIntersitial();
                   
                    },
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15.0, horizontal: 20.0),
                      child: Text(
                        'إعادة الحساب',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                    ),
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.pink,
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  MobileAds.instance.initialize();
  runApp(BMICalculatorApp());
}

PS: i also have ad mob code in androidmanifest file and infot file and imported the packages
post integrating mobile ad dependency build message :

Note: C:\Users\RGG\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\google_mobile_ads-5.1.0\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\googlemobileads\FlutterRequestAgentProvider.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
C:/Users/RGG/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.8.21/43d50ab85bc7587adfe3dda3dbe579e5f8d51265/kotlin-stdlib-1.8.21.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.


Edit your android/settings.gradle file, and in the plugins { ... } section, change the entry for kotlin to match the latest version.
I currently have:
plugins {
    // other plugins
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "2.0.10" apply false
}

You can find out the latest stable version of kotlin at: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/home.html
Hope this helps.
